# Random Picking an XMLList menuitem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, random, flexbuilder, xmllist

i have this XMLList:

```
<fx:XMLList id="Generic List" xmlns="">
        <menuitem label="First entry" url="www.aaa.com"/>
        <menuitem label="Second entry" url="www.bbb.com"/>
        <menuitem label="Third Entry" url="www.ccc.com"/>
</fx:XMLList>
```

I want to randomly select in my combobox (code not displayed) one of these menu item picked randomly.
I'm using Flex Builder 4,6.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to do something by yourself? Do you want to have a combobox which gets items from this List and sets one of the items as selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XMLList id="genericList" xmlns="">
        <menuitem label="First entry" url="www.aaa.com"/>
        <menuitem label="Second entry" url="www.bbb.com"/>
        <menuitem label="Third Entry" url="www.ccc.com"/>
    </fx:XMLList>
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:ComboBox 
    id="cbEntry" 
    dataProvider="{new XMLListCollection(genericList)}" 
    labelField="@label" 
    creationComplete="{cbEntry.selectedIndex = Math.floor(cbEntry.dataProvider.length * Math.random());}"/>

</s:Application>
```